# ADT Logcat Filters disappear and stop working

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, logcat

Sometimes when I'm using the ADT plugin for Eclipse my LogCat filters just disappear for no reason.

My problem is when I click on the [+] button to add a LogCat filter and type something in the Filter name field and my application name on the Application name field and I click OK, the filter does not work.

I have made sure that my application name is `bee.mobile` but it doesn't work, I tried to create a lot of filters in different ways with no success.

How I can solve this?

Comment: did you tried resetting your ADB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem too and it took several hours to solve. First you must `End Task` your `ADB` process from task manager and reopen eclipse again. Then add an error exception in your code intentional (like division by zero or somthing else). This make force `logcat` to show an error in the correct session not in the package name that you was adding into `logcat`. Do this methods and tell me if it not working. If `LogCat` shows error in session itself is better than you filter with package name. Sometime you have to run your Android Project 2 or more times with errors to force logcat shows your error. Unfortunately It seems big problem in Eclipse.

Comment: yay! I did exactly what you explained below and the session filter lives again ! many thanks :)